# how do you test csv file content in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm writing a simple CanadaPost price shipping API, where the prices are given in a PDF document in table format (see page 3 of https://www.canadapost.ca/tools/pg/prices/SBParcels-e.pdf).

The data is extracted into csv files and imported into the database (table *prices* has columns *weight*, *rate_code* and *date*). The model and controller are very simple: they take a *weight*, *rate_code* and *date* and query the prices table.

I'm trying to create a suite of tests which tests the existence and correctness of every single price in that chart. It has to be generic and reusable because the data changes every year.

I thought of some ideas:

> 1) Read the same csv files that were used to import the data into the database and create a single RSpec example that loops around all rows and columns and tests the returned price.
>
> 2) Convert the csv files into fixtures for the *prices* controller and test each fixture.

I'm also having a hard time categorizing these tests. They are not unit tests, but are they really functional/feature tests? They sound more like integration tests, but I'm not sure if Rails differentiates functional tests from integration tests.

Maybe the answer is obvious and I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a right way to do this, but the unit tests for the models and controllers were too difficult to write. There was too much mocking involved. The fixture files also didn't work. They were too large and too slow. I ended up putting these tests into Postman as system integration tests and it worked out well.

Answer (score 0):

> Program testing can be a very effective way to show the presence of bugs, but is hopelessly inadequate for showing their absence (Edsger Wybe Dijkstra)

First of all, I think you should assume that the CSV parser did its job correctly.

Once you did this, get the output CSV file and put it in your specs (`fixtures`, `require`, `load`), then test that the output is the one you see.

If it is correct for every single line of this csv file (I'm assuming it's a big one given what I say in your link), then I would conclude that your code works. I wouldn't bother testing it every year, unless it would make you feel very secure about your code.

You might get an anomaly afterwards, but unfortunalely your specs cannot detect that. it can simply ensure that it works great for this year's data.

Comment: After reading some more, I'm not sure putting my expected data in fixtures is the way to go. Fixtures hold setup data, whereas this is expected data. Tons and tons of expected data. Perhaps an environment outside Rails (like Selenium) might be the right technology for this.

Comment: I thought about it some more, and I realized that I don't even have a model to save my fixtures data into. My price request is just for a controller. There is no model for it and I'm not sure creating a model for testing purposes is a good idea.

Comment: I would put the `expected` data (i.e. what should have been inserted in the DB) in the specs themselves. I wouldn't necessary load the last year's CSV data in fixtures (I personally do not use fixtures), but rather in a file that you can require from your specs (a dumb `require` in your test file would do the trick here)